# applying precision of 3digits after decimal to string getting Runtime Exception

Tags: android, floating-point, runtimeexception

I am applying precision of 3digits after decimal to string which holds a float value and set it to edittext once another edittext is accessed

```
final float f = Float.valueOf(eproductprice.getText().toString());
ebuilding.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            //Log.e("Float","Message"+f);
            String productprice=String.format("%.3f", f);
            eproductprice.setText(productprice);
        }
    }
});
```

Here eproductprice I want to set the format float input and ebuilding is the next `edittext`

I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    
ComponentInfo{com.omega.waselapp/com.omega.waselapp.Pickupdetails_activity}:  
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `eproductprice.getText().` inside `onFocusChange` to get value from EditText:

```
@Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!hasFocus)
                {       
                   // get value here from EditText
                 float f = Float.valueOf(eproductprice.getText().toString()); 
                 String productprice=String.format("%.3f", f);
                 eproductprice.setText(productprice);
         }
    }
```

And before calling `String.format` make sure String is not emty to avoid `NumberFormatException`  or handle `NumberFormatException` using `try-catch`